# ImageDraw.text() drawing text in wrong location

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

To begin with, here's my existing code:

```
def GenerateText(self, size, text):
    font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/arial.ttf', size)
    size = font.getsize(text)

    im = Image.new('RGBA', size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

    draw.text((0, 0), text, font=font)

    return im
```

The function just takes some text and a font size, and then attempts to generate an image of the appropriate size to write the font into. However, whenever I save the returned image, it looks like it's not actually drawing the text at (0,0). It's always pasting slightly lower than it should be, which has the effect of clipping the bottom of the text.

Here's an image of what I mean, using the text "Test":

[image: test image]

I'm calling the function as GenerateText(100, "Test").

Comment: Works for me.  Maybe it's related to the particular ttf file you're using?  Try with different fonts...

Comment: No dice. I tried every font in the msttcorefonts directory in addition to the built-in fonts. They all do the same thing.

Comment: I ended up just modifying the size of the image being pasted into like this:

im = Image.new('RGBA', (size[0], int(size[1] * 1.3)), (0, 0, 0, 0))

Comment: Works with '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSansBold.ttf' on PIL 1.1.7.

Comment: I'm using Pillow. That might have something to do with it.. I tried the same code under Windows 7 using the same version of Pillow, and I had the same problem. I'm going to check the code and see if anything differs in the fork.. that's really the only other thing I can think of that would be causing the problem, since it persists across different linux distros AND into Windows.